# Properties of A.T * A and A * A.T given A

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

Consolidated properties of $A^TA$ (Gram Matrix) and $AA^T$ given $A$:

[image]

I prepared this after going through multiple posts and wikipedia definitions etc. I'm not very sure of the Positive Definite and Positive Semi-Definite conclusions I made.

Comment: Are you intentionally making the assumption that the diagonal matrix is invertible for some reason? If it has a 0 on the diagonal, then the conclusions about determinant, psdness, and eigenvalues are incorrect.

Comment: @imu96 Definition of diagonal matrix => A matrix having non-zero elements only in the diagonal running from the upper left to the lower right.

Comment: @Ram However, that doesn't mean the diagonal elements can't be zero.

Comment: @sudeep5221 It is not called a diagonal matrix if it's diagonal elements are 0